# oData NOT In with subquery equivalent

Tags: odata

Is it possible to reproduce a query such as the following using an oData filter?

```
SELECT 
   st.*
FROM
   SomeTable st
WHERE 
   st.ID  NOT IN 
   (SELECT LinkedID FROM SomeTable)
```

This isnt quite my real world example, but essentially what I'm trying to achieve in to get all the results that aren't returned in sub-query, but being able to do the above would achieve what I need, if its possible.